# combinatorics problem: ordering people from small to large. Is my solution correct?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, alternative-proof

**Question:** is my solution to the following problem correct? I'm also interested in (possibly) more elegant solutions.

I have the following problem: 
Suppose there are $n$ people of different length and assign them a place in a row on an arbitrary basis. The chance that we can fix the order from small to large by switching two people, equals $1/48$. How many people are there?

**My solution**
The number of ways we can put these people in a line equals $n!$.

The number of sequences where there are 2 people not on the right spot equals $\binom{n}{2}$; starting from the right order, we need to pick two people, without repetition, and switch them. This gives a sequence of people which can be fixed by exactly one switch. The number of ways to do this equals $\binom{n}{2}$.

Hence the chance of a sequence where 2 people are in the wrong spot equals 
$$\frac{\binom{n}{2}}{n!} = \frac{1}{48}.$$
Writing things out, we find that this equals to
$$48\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = n!$$
and hence 
$$24 = (n-2)!$$
which gives $n = 6$.

Comment: I think it is correct, and cannot find a way that is essentially better of more elegant.

Comment: @drhab Initially I was unsure if this was indeed the correct answer, but while writing it down, I gained some confidence in this answer. Thank you for your feedback. What do I do with this question? Do I write an answer of my own or just delete it?

Comment: Yes, I also got the same answer. I believe the method you've mentioned is already quite concise and elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

Your solution is correct.